# Como verificar se a conexão caiu antes de enviar um dado via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var erroEnvio = false; //global

$(".proxima-questao").on("click",function(){
    $(".loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlBase+"123123123/adasdasdasdas",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success:function(resposta){
            if(resposta === "sucesso"){
                erroEnvio = false;
                setSuccessEnvio(erroEnvio);
                $(".loading").hide();
            } else {
                erroEnvio = true;
                setSuccessEnvio(erroEnvio);
                $(".loading").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});

function setSuccessEnvio(x){
    erroEnvio = x;
}


 if(erroEnvio === false) {
    // a idéia é salvar os dados antes de ir pro próximo bloco
    proximaQuestao();
} else {
    alert("Erro");
}

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return "sucesso";
    } else {
        return "falha";
    }
```

uma coisa que notei é que está retornando sucesso mesmo com a conexão caida.

Quando eu fico offline, eu consigo ir para a próxima questão, depois que eu estou no próximo bloco, se eu clicar de novo no `botão próxima questão` ele mostra esse alerta de Erro.

Comment: Porque você tem `setSuccessEnvio` se sua alteração no `erroEnvio` já vai para a global?

Comment: Nao precisa testar antes de enviar. Você envia e vê se deu certo pelo retorno do Ajax, e toma a providência necessária com base nisso.

Answer (score 1):

Não é no sucesso que você deve verificar se ocorreu algum erro de conexão ou erro na parte do servidor,
você deve usar o .error do próprio ajax.

Se você estiver utilizando a versão do jQuery igual ou inferior a 1.8 utilize success e error da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'arquivo.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Informe aqui que a conexão caiu ou que houve algum problema
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
   }
});
```

Se for acima de 1.8 use done e fail:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'arquivo.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   done: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   },
   fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Informe aqui que a conexão caiu ou que houve algum problema
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
   }
});
```

**Dica:** Você pode utilizar o beforeSend e o complete para colocar a sua imagem de load e criar uma função genérica para  fazer estas requisições usando o then:

```
 var request = function(url, data) {
   return $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: data,
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function() {
       $("img").show();
     },
     complete: function() {
       $("img").hide();
     },error: function(data) {
        $("div").append(data.statusText);
     }
   });
 };


 request("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler").then(function(data) {
   $("div").append(data);
 });
```

**Exemplo:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/2bLumoLf/2/)